# Receiving value from QgsPropertyOverrideButton if data defined override is checked

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to develop a plugin for QGIS 3. For me it is quite the first time really working with pyqgis or python, so there might be something simple I am missing.

I want to use data defined override button within this plugin. If it is checked, the used value should be taken from this button (expression or attribute) instead of a spinbox. This is my layout with the button:

[image]

Unfortunately I could not find any documentation or related questions, which explain how to actually use this `QgsPropertyOverrideButton`. So I am only able to grab the value from the spinbox. This is my relevant code snipped:

```
    #Check where to gather attributes from: GUI or Layer?
    if self.dlg.Isochrones_WalkSpeed_Override.isActive() == True:
        WalkSpeed = self.dlg.Isochrones_WalkSpeed_Override.value() #Receiving Value from GUI: DataDefinedOverride
    else:            
        WalkSpeed = self.dlg.Isochrones_WalkSpeed.value() #Receiving Value from GUI: SpinBox
```

How do I grab the value from there either via an attribute from layer or via a given expression within edit field?

[image]

Comment: You have the official documentation, if it's checked emit this https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPropertyOverrideButton.html#a3e6bd992662d1743ce7c1c3002ffd6cb and maybe the qgis test too test_qgspropertyoverridebutton.py

Comment: Thx, figured out I have to use `.isActive()` to check if the button is active, but still struggling to figure out how to grab the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you should use `toProperty()` method, which returns `QgsProperty`. Then you can use `value()` or `valueAs***()` methods of `QgsProperty` to get value of defined expression. Or you can get raw expression string with `expressionString()` method. See docs for  [QgsProperty](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProperty.html).

EDIT

`value()` and  `valueAs***()` returns tuple where first element is actual value and second element is bool reffering to successfulness of conversion. So, it is possible to use python tuple unpacking feature like so:

```
val, success = property.value(context)
if success:
    doSomenthingWith(val)
```

So in your case you would need to write as example:

```
WalkSpeed, success = self.dlg.Isochrones_WalkSpeed_Override.toProperty().value(QgsExpressionContext())
```

Comment: Acording to PyQgis documentation, value() returns Tuple[Any, bool], which is exactly what you get. Firs element is actual value, second element contains information about succes of conversion. It corespond to 'ok' pointer parameter in C++ function call. So dont hasitate to use returned tuple ;)